# What does "Murió de un calambre" mean?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, significado

I just finished *Cuentos Alegres*, a book assigned to me in Spanish class forty years ago. The book itself may be over 100 years old in its original printing.

In the last story, a Sherlock Holmes story, the phrase "murió de un calambre" was used. A literal translation would be "died of a cramp". It's also what Google translate tells me. Does it mean died from a seizure? It this an old usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see the definition for *calambre* as it was a hundred years ago. This is written in the Royal Spanish Academy's dictionary from 1914:

> **Calambre.** (Del ant. nórdico *klampi*, laña, corchete; en al. *krampf*, calambre.) m. Contracción espamódica, involuntaria, dolorosa y poco durable de ciertos músculos, particularmente de los de la pantorrilla.

No trace of the *electrical shock*-related meaning, neither in this dictionary nor in other dictionaries from the same time. That meaning was added to the dictionary in 1992. In fact, a hundred years ago the term to refer to an electrical shoch was *descarga eléctrica*:

> *Tona sufrió una sacudida de arriba abajo, como si la hubieran aplicado una descarga eléctrica [...].*
>
> José María de Pereda, "Peñas arriba", 1895 (Spain).

In the aforementioned dictionary you can read:

> **Descarga.** Acción y efecto de descargar.
>   **Descargar.** <sup>5</sup> Anular la tensión eléctrica de un cuerpo haciendo saltar la chispa o por otro medio.

So it seems that the person died indeed from a cramp. And yes, the word *calambre* dates from very old, it can be found in the Spanish-Latin dictionary by Antonio de Nebrija, written in 1495.

Reading this text from circa 1535 it seems that people could indeed die from a cramp:

> *"Pereçosa,
>
>   vellaca, puerca, golosa,
>
>   mala hembra, desoluta;
>
>   di, ¿no acabas, çancajosa?
>
>   ¡Ven aquí, borracha puta!
>
>   Dormillona,
>
>   ¿de dónde vienes, soplona?
>
>   ¡Mueras de mala calambre!"*
>
> Anónimo, "Auto de Clarindo", c1535 (Spain).

The last sentence means "may you die from a bad cramp". By the way, it seems that Spanish *calambre* and English *cramp* have the same origin.

Answer (score 3):

Calambre can have many meanings. See the [DRAE's entry for "Calambre"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6h4MzHa). One is actually a cramp

> 1. m. **Contracción muscular** involuntaria, dolorosa y de poca duración.

(same for the third entry, a "*espasmo de ciertos grupos de músculos*") But it can also be an electric shock

> 2. m. Sacudida producida por una **descarga eléctrica** de baja intensidad.

It seems difficult, but not impossible, that a person would die from either of these, specially in a work of fiction. Without any context, after hearing

> murió de un calambre

I could not tell if it was cramp or an electric shock.

Comment: it's the cramp *produced by* the shock, not the shock itself.

Comment: @ths No. it's an electric shock in the terms of a _jolt_. That might _shake_ the part of the body that received the electric shock. That area might get cramped, numbed or in pain, but I believe the definition does not imply "the cramp you get **after or due to** the shock". It means "the jolt of an electric shock".

Comment: in any case it seems pretty clear that it means the physiological reaction to the shock.

Comment: But when you translate to English, you'll want to convey "he died from the outcome of muscular cramp" or "he died from the outcome of a low intensity  electric shock". "Died of a cramp" although technically accurate for both, may not be the best translation for "murió de un calambre", depending on the context (which is unknown). "Died of a cramp" could be misleading if the originator was an electric shock.